# How the ADAS_ATTRIB attribute vertical_flags has to be interpreted

Tags: here-api

I'm playing a little with the route matching function of here api.
And I stumbled across an ADAS_ATTRIB attribute called VERTICAL_FLAGS.

The only time it's mentioned in the docs is (at least what I've found so far):
`"Y/N. Specifies for each coordinate point along the link, whether it was introduced on a straight road section, because of height changes. If Y then this shape point exists only in the ADAS link gemoetry, but not in the standard road geometry."`

Regarding this, how can a sample output like this:

```
"shape": "49.00027 12.12437 49.00024 12.12431 49.00002 12.12399",
 "attributes": {
     "ADAS_ATTRIB_FCN": [
          {
           "SLOPES": "[-86, 157, 60, -1]",
           "CURVATURES": "[-3051, -1015]",
           "HPZ": "[38522, 0, 3, 1]",
           "VERTICAL_FLAGS": "[1, 0]"
          }
       ]
    },
```

be interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

Each link(road) is represented as a polyline between two nodes in Here map data. This polyline contains one or more shapepoints which represent the shape of the link. Data is represented as different layers in the map (for ease of storage). The road topology layer data contains basic map data like links and nodes information(along with shape points). Shape points are points on a link which are introduced whenever there is a change in road goemetry, etc. In addition to the shape points present in road topology layer, ADAS layer might have introduced some more shape points in the same link for representing ADAS information(eg: road height change, curvature etc). VERTICAL_FLAGS represents whether the shape points found for a link in ADAS attribute is also present in topology segment or not.

You can read about the entire list of ADAS Attributes available here https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=18150&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1 (login with Here credentials). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and clearification of the attribute! But how are the values of "VERTICAL_FLAGS": "[1, 0]" interpreted? Is in this case [1,0] referring to shape points or to attributes like SLOPE? Because normally I get more attributes than shape points. And which index are they referring to?